# Function for row insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql

I am relatively newbie with SQL Server, and I have some experience and practices from Oracle & PostgreSQL which i want to use in the SQL Server.

I need to create function which takes fields values for new row in the table and which also returning autogenerated ID value of the new record.

First of all I am faced with the fact that the functions in SQL Server can not change data in the tables. The second my discovery was that is the procedures in SQL Server can return values through `return @result` construction.

I investigate `output` mechanism of the DML queries, but they returns not scalar but table results.

Be patient and let me more clear. There is PostgreSQL function which doing what I want:

Table creation script:

```
create table foobar
(
  foo bigint not null default nextval('s_foobar'::regclass),
  bar character varying(16),
  constraint pk_foobar primary key (foo)
);
```

and function script:

```
create or replace function f_foobar_insert(p_bar character varying)
  returns integer as
$body$declare
  result integer;
begin
  insert into foobar(bar) values (p_bar) returning foo into result;
  return result;
end;$body$ language plpgsql;
```

Is there any possibility to make something like this in SQL Server in the same way?

Comment: @marc-s Thanks for attention. I am not sure about replacing "MS SQL" to "SQL server" In my mind "SQL server" is a program which serves SQL queries on the some data. So "SQL server" can be anything such as Firebird, Postgres, SQLite, Oracle and so on. Do not call "SQL server" only one, not perfect product created by M$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, the table creation would be:

```
create table foobar
(
  foo bigint not null identity primary key,
  bar varchar(16)
);
```

The following is one way in SQL Server to get the functionality:

```
insert into foobar(bar) select 'value';

select @@identity;
```

This is not really the preferred way.  You should really use the `output` clause:

```
declare @t table (foo bigint);

insert into foobar(bar)
    output inserted.foo into @t
    select 'value';

select foo from @t;
```

You can wrap this in a stored procedure if you like, but it doesn't seem necessary, and stored procedures have different semantics from functions.

Comment: Sorry for silly question. Is there any purpose for using `select 'value'` instead of `values ('value')` in the your example? Is this necessary or just a habit? Yes, it works in the both ways, but why you prefer one then another? Thanks for attention.

Comment: I prefer `insert . . . select` because it does everything `insert . . . values` does, and more.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. And yep. `declare @t table (foo bigint);` and `select foo from @t;` works fine, but there is no any way to catch and return only one value from query. In the other words: in my example (lets return to them) ` insert into foobar(bar) values (p_bar) returning foo into result;` returns inserted value inti the `result` variable. Is there any ways to do it with MSSQL?

Comment: @Abelisto . . . In SQL Server, a user defined function cannot modify the database.  You could do what you want with a stored procedure, but stored procedures do not return values the way a function does.

Comment: And the last thing: `select @result = foo from @t;`. Thank you for the answer.